# Problem with Passing Null String Between Classes in Java

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to pass a string from one class to another, but instead of it passing the string I need, it's passing a null value, which causes an error in the decryption function I'm trying to do. Here are the two classes with details on each one that I'm trying to achieve:

MainActivity -> trying to take the value I get from "String decrypted1 = d1.encryppass(encrypted);"

```
                    Decrypt d1 = new Decrypt();
                try {
                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        do {
                            String name = cursor.getString(0);
                            String encrypted = cursor.getString(1);
                            d1.myMethod(this);
                            decrypted1 = d1.encryppass(encrypted);
                            Log.i("Title:     ", name);
                            Log.i("Password:  ", decrypted1);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), decrypted1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                    }
                } catch (NullPointerException exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Decryption 2 class -> and pass that above statement here "private String pinToMd5 = d3.decrypted1;"

```
public class Decrypt2 {
    private Cipher cipher;
    MainActivity d3;
    private String pinToMd5;
    public String pin_to_md5;SecretKeySpec secretKeySpe = new SecretKeySpec(this.pin_to_md5.getBytes(), "AES");

    public Decrypt2(MainActivity mainActivity)
        {
        d3 = mainActivity;
        pinToMd5 = d3.decrypted1;
        pin_to_md5 = MD5(pinToMd5);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see the issue might be here

```
MainActivity d3 = new MainActivity();
    //private String pinToMd5 = "PaSsW0rD"; //use this to test my code to confirm any changes doesn't break the logic -> this works
    private String pinToMd5 = d3.decrypted1;
```

You are creating new instance from MainActivity class and expect the object from the one presented in the stack. Try passing the context or reference from the existing main activity class and assign it in the Decrypt class

```
    InputStream instream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(singleUri);
/*Reference from MainActivity class*/
                        Decrypt2 d2 = new Decrypt2(this);
                        String decrypted2 = d2.encrypnote(instream);

public class Decrypt2 {
//your code...

MainActivity d3;
    //private String pinToMd5 = "PaSsW0rD"; //use this to test my code to confirm any changes doesn't break the logic -> this works
private String pinToMd5;

public Decrypt2(MainActivity mainActivity)
{
    d3 = mainActivity;
    pinToMd5 = d3.decrypted1;
}
//your code...
}
```

Not sure this will fix your problem completely :)

Second issue is this code here:

public String pin_to_md5 = MD5(pinToMd5);

You are invoking the method MD5 before the pinToMd5 property is initialised? when did you need to use that class? If on the initialization of the class than do this changes in the code:

```
public class Decrypt2 {
//your code...

MainActivity d3;
    //private String pinToMd5 = "PaSsW0rD"; //use this to test my code to confirm any changes doesn't break the logic -> this works
private String pinToMd5;
//remove MD5(pinToMd5);
public String pin_to_md5;
SecretKeySpec secretKeySpe;


public Decrypt2(MainActivity mainActivity)
{
    d3 = mainActivity;
    pinToMd5 = d3.decrypted1;
    pin_to_md5 = MD5(pinToMd5);
    secretKeySpe = new SecretKeySpec(this.pin_to_md5.getBytes(), "AES");

}
//your code...
}
```

Third issue
In MainActivity you are using

```
public String decrypted1 = "";
```

as property. But then in onClick method you are creating local variable that contains the encrypted string

```
     d1.myMethod(this);
//this code here
     String decrypted1 = d1.encryppass(encrypted);
    
     Log.i("Title:     ", name);
```

Local values live only inside the method but not in the class so instead creating new variable in the method use the one from above. Remove that String .. and make the code smth like this

```
d1.myMethod(this);
//this code here
decrypted1 = d1.encryppass(encrypted);
        
Log.i("Title:     ", name);
```

Comment: What you put actually makes sense.  I did run into one issue when compiling in my MainActivity.  I'm going to update my original post with the error.

Comment: @cbates79 can you add the changes in the classes too, so I can see how you made the fixes? This error usually appears when you are using the default constructor and not the argumented one. Did you pass the reference *this* in MainActivity class? Do you have any other places in the MainActivity where you use Decrypt2 class but with default constructor?

Comment: I updated the code.  That should be the only spot using Decrypt2.  I have some code that uses another class called just Decrypt, but that part is working without issue.  I did miss the "this" reference.  I updated that, but now my app crashes.  updating with the error I get.  It's going back to a null error.

Comment: As I can read from the error this is different null pointer exception is on *MD5*     public String pin_to_md5 = MD5(pinToMd5);
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpe = new SecretKeySpec(this.pin_to_md5.getBytes(), "AES"); // null ref. What is this MD5?

Comment: In this statement stays clearly  *Attempt to invoke virtual method 'byte[] java.lang.String.getBytes()' on a null object reference.* pin_to_md5 object is null and you are trying to invoke function on null object

Comment: Tip: Please use debugging so you can easily track where your issues comes from

Comment: Ok, let me make the changes and I'll see.  If it still crashes, I'll use debugging.  You don't know how much I appreciate this.  I've bee at this app for a few days and I feel this is the last part I need to get working.

Comment: It is fine to write the next issue, I would like to help :) Your code is complex and it runs in multiple issues as we can see from the errors :) Debugging is essential definitely

Comment: It still crashed.  Let me update the Decrypt2 code.  Just so you can see what is shows now.  I'll post the error and then try to get some debugging going.

Comment: Check the changes

Comment: I updated everything.  looks like a similar issue based on the reference in logcat.  Maybe it's this line:
 public String pin_to_md5;SecretKeySpec secretKeySpe = new SecretKeySpec(this.pin_to_md5.getBytes(), "AES");

I know this line worked when i had the password hard coded.  Not sure what's going on with it now.

Comment: Try assigning secretKeySpe in the constructor too, following the example from above. If you still get the error there are great possibilities that pin_to_md5 is null during some issues in MD5 method. Also add another catch block with catch(Exception e){ exception.printStackTrace();} in MD5 method to see if pin_to_md5 failed to be set on some value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221294/discussion-between-cbates79-and-stefanija).